# detect change url with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, web

Is there solutions how to find out when browser change url ? I have code which take for me data from web. I use `.clik` for next page in my url, but I don´t know how to do stop on the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your instance of WebDriver, you should be able to get the current URL using:

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
string url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: yes thanks, this is way how to do it ! I can compare url.

Comment: Glad to help :)